# How to add Socket and WinAPI tracing to .NET Core console application?

Tags: c#, .net-core, trace

In classic .NET app, I did this by adding the following in app.config:

```xml
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
    <listeners>
      <add name="System.Net"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.Cache">
    <listeners>
      <add name="System.Net"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.Http">
    <listeners>
      <add name="System.Net"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
    <listeners>
      <add name="System.Net"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.WebSockets">
    <listeners>
      <add name="System.Net"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<switches>
  <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
  <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose"/>
  <add name="System.Net.Http" value="Verbose"/>
  <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
  <add name="System.Net.WebSockets" value="Verbose"/>
</switches>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="System.Net" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="network.log"/>
</sharedListeners>
<trace autoflush="true"/>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Can I achieve the same effect in .NET Core console app? In particular, I need to see which WinAPI functions are called (and which parameters are passed) during NTLM authentication with NegotiateStream class.

What I found so far is mostly about logging Web APIs in ASP.NET Core apps. My app is not ASP.NET, neither it uses any web APIs.

Comment: If you are using the new SDK-based project files, you'll need to manually add <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>.

Comment: And what would be the effect of this? From your reply, I don't see how to specify the log filename..

Comment: I don't have a full solution for you. I just have one piece of the solution. I know from personal experience that defining the TRACE constant is a prerequisite for the .NET tracing to output anything. The dotnet new templates do not define that constant by default.

Answer (score 1):

For the new .NET 5 you may try the technique mentioned [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-5-new-networking-improvements/#telemetry)  and it uses EventListener.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core tracing works differently compared to .NET framework. The framework emits trace events through etw (in windows). To read trace events you have two choices:

- use an external tool that can parse etw logs (dotnet-trace, perfmon, perfview, an app you wrote using the [traceevent library](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview/releases/tag/T2.0.56))
- in code, by registering a custom [EventListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventlistener?view=netcore-3.0) class. E.g see this excellent article from redhat.com: [link](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/12/23/tracing-net-core-applications/)